# What are the details of dynamic symbol binding on OS X?

Tags: c, macos, dyld

I have a really odd situation with dynamic symbol binding on OS X that I'm hoping to get some clues on how to resolve.

I have an application, written in C, which uses `dlopen()` to dynamically load modules at runtime. Some of these modules export global symbols, which may be used by other modules loaded later.

We have one module (which I'll call `weird_module.so`) which exports global symbols, one of which is `weird_module_function`. If weird_module.so gets linked with a particular library (which I'll call `libsomething.dylib`), then `weird_module_function` can't be bound to. But if I remove the `-lsomething` when linking `weird_module.so`, then I *can* bind to `weird_module_function`.

What could possibly be going on with `libsomething.dylib` that would cause `weird_module.so` to not export symbols? Are there things I can do to debug how symbols get exported (similar to how I can use `DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS` to debug how they get bound)?

```
$ LDFLAGS="-bundle -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -undefined -Xlinker dynamic_lookup /usr/lib/bundle1.o"

$ gcc -o weird_module.so ${LDFLAGS} weird_module.o -lsomething
$ nm weird_module.so | grep '_weird_module_function$'
00000000000026d0 T _weird_module_function

$ gcc -o other_module.so ${LDFLAGS} other_module.o -lsomething
$ nm other_module.so | grep '_weird_module_function$'
                 U _weird_module_function

$ run-app
Loading weird_module.so
Loading other_module.so
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _weird_module_function
  Referenced from: other_module.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _weird_module_function
  Referenced from: other_module.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

# Now relink without -lsomething
$ gcc -o weird_module.so ${LDFLAGS} weird_module.o
$ nm weird_module.so | grep '_weird_module_function$'
00000000000026d0 T _weird_module_function
$ run-app
Loading weird_module.so
Loading other_module.so
# No error!
```

*Edit*:

I tried putting together a minimal app to duplicate the problem, and in the course of doing so at least figured it out one thing we were doing wrong. There are two other pertinent facts relevant to duplicating the issue.

First is that `run-app` preloads the module with `RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL` to inspect its metadata. The module is then `dlclose()`ed and reopened with either `RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL` or `RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL`, depending on the metadata. (For both modules in question, it reopens with `RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL`).

Secondly, there turns out to be a symbol collision in `weird_module.so` and `libsomething.dylib` for a `const` global.

```
$ nm weird_module.so | grep '_something_global`
00000000000158f0 S _something_global

$ nm libsomething.dylib | grep '_something_global'
0000000000031130 S _something_global
```

I'm willing to consider that the duplicate symbol would put me in the realm of undefined behavior, so I'm dropping the question.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to reproduce your scenario and I was able to get the same errors as you, i.e. `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed` followed by `dyld: Symbol not found`.

But it had nothing to do with linking against `libsomething.dylib` or not. What I did to trigger this error was just calling `weird_module_function()` from the constructor of `other_module.so`:

```
//  other_module.c

#import <stdio.h>
#import "weird_module.h"

__attribute__((constructor)) void initialize_other_module(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    weird_module_function();
}
```

Here is how I loaded the modules:

```
//  main.c

#import <stdio.h>
#import <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("\nLoading weird module\n");
    void *weird = dlopen("weird_module.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
    printf("weird: %p\n\n", weird);

    printf("Loading other module\n");
    void *other = dlopen("other_module.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
    printf("other: %p\n", other);

    return 0;
}
```

The dyld errors disappear if I remove the `RTLD_LOCAL` option when loading `weird_module.so`.

The same error also occurs if you call `weird_module_function` from a `libsomething.dylib` constructor but it happens before `main` is called so that’s probably not what is happening to you.

But maybe the `libsomething.dylib` constructor is where you should look to find how `libsomething.dylib` is influencing your modules loading process. You can set the `DYLD_PRINT_INITIALIZERS` environment variable to `YES` in order to find out what constructors are called.

A few other things to check:

1. Are you 100% sure that both modules are reopened with `RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL`? The only way I could get the dyld errors was by passing the `RTLD_LOCAL` option.
2. Are you sure the the `dlclose` call is successful (returns 0)? If, for example, your module contains Objective-C code, it will not be unloaded.